# React Router: Replace location state then goBack, location state is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

```
this.props.history.replace({
  state: {
    from: 'dashboard'
  }
});

this.props.history.goBack();
```

The value of `this.props.location.state` is `undefined` when used `this.props.history.goBack()` after updating the `this.props.location.state`. But

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/',
  state: {
    from: 'dashboard'
  }
});
```

works and retains the value of `this.props.location.state`.

Any idea how can I update `this.props.location.state` then use `this.props.history.goBack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to the official docs:**

- push(path, [state]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history stack
- replace(path, [state]) - (function) Replaces the current entry on the history stack
- go(n) - (function) Moves the pointer in the history stack by n entries
- goBack() - (function) Equivalent to go(-1)
- goForward() - (function) Equivalent to go(1)

so better to use `this.props.history.push({})` if you want to use `goBack()`

for better understanding you can visit [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history), [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

Comment: Yup. But using `push` as a replacement of `goBack` will mess the `routing flow` since it will push a new entry into the history stack instead of removing the current entry in order to go back to the previous one.

Comment: my location.state was undefined. I included state also in history.replace() and it fixed my problem. Thanks.